# Bootstrap 5 floating labels overlapping

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-5, floating-labels

does anyboy have a solution for visualizing longer text without overflow hidden/ellipsis, where the related text is truncated? Cause some questions of input fields make no sense while u just see the half of it.
The problem based on the official Bootstrap 5 example page for floating labels:
[image]

Comment: Floating labels _are_ pretty bad from a usability perspective anyway, so the best solution would IMHO be to just ditch them.

Comment: @CBroe well this is not a "solution", its more what it ends up with if no solution is found :D

Comment: Floating labels aren’t a solution to begin with, they _are_ a problem. https://medium.com/simple-human/floating-labels-are-a-bad-idea-82edb64220f6 They are designer vanity at the expense of usability.

Comment: @CBroe most of the issues i faced on my website and fixed them all: no space, small text is hard to read, they need space to move into, poor contrast, inconsistently located - BUT yeah, you are right - They are trouble makers... The hard thing is that the current problem will force me to remove all my work regarding the previous ones. I will end up with ditch them, as you mentioned :-(

Comment: Related issue which uses ellipsis... https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/36270

Answer (score 0):

You can use autowrap.

```css
input{
    height:50px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
    white-space:pre-line;  
    position:relative;
    top:-15px;
}

::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
    white-space:pre-line;  
    position:relative;
    top:-15px;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
    white-space:pre-line;  
    position:relative;
    top:-15px;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    white-space:pre-line;  
    position:relative;
    top:-15px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Anzahl der am 17.07. (seit min 14 Tagen!) vollstandig geimpften/von Corona genesenen Personen" size="30">
```

Comment: not really working, as long as you go only with placeholder which then get invisible you are fine - But seriously how does a form look, with only answers. Imagine just numeric answers :D. 1,2,1,3,1 - What where the related questions?

Comment: When there are only numeric value, you can use <input type="number">. Anyway, I've provided a code snippet. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: no, as soon as you reply/answer you don't see the related question for it [numeric input field eg](https://i.ibb.co/v49jH1h/image.png) - i just want a "simple" wrap so that the question is still readable

Answer (score 0):

I used them in a lot of forms on a site and ran into the same problem, longer text labels are overlapping the input and select values.
However the solution I used without replacing the entire html to ditch them was to set their position to relative. By default they are positioned as absolute. Just a line of css to change the positioning to relative will make them display under the input element.

```
.form-floating > label {
    position: relative !important;
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why not use normal labels instead of floating labels, if you want the labels to be below/above the input?